# How to merge time-lapse videos and soundtrack?

Tags: music, video, quicktime, 3gp

I want to create video clip with merged time-lapse short videos and a soundtrack accompanying it. I would prefer as short a learning curve as possible and a rapid  way to accomplish this. Adobe Premiere, but it seems too expensive for something I will barely use.

My upload speed is too slow for online video editing *(1Mb/s - 120 KB/s)*, so I prefer to do everything on my local 2.6 Ghz dual core Intel processor based laptop with 8GB of RAM. I already have 2 5-7 second time lapse videos, 30 short videos and over 500 photos to choose from and only need to glue everything into over 4 minutes of soundtrack playback. I could use more soundtracks if needed of course but I want there to be transition between soundtracks. Videos were shot in 3GP and MOV formats.

I appreciate your help and guidance as well as information on software (I very much prefer free or open source) I should use to accomplish this project.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any video editing software can do this - if you have Windows, you can use Moviemaker (free, bundled with Microsoft Live these days)

The idea is you populate the timeline with all your video clips, and add whatever transitions you need, then add your audio to the sound track.

The only problem is that Moviemaker does not support 3Gp, so use a free converter to change to mpg first.

Comment: Any other software that you know of?

Comment: Google for video editing software windows- there are lots.

Comment: Can I do what I want in my YouTube account with their video editor?

Comment: Not easily, no. Just download one of the free apps like moviemaker.